# How to set up triple monitors to work as a single screen on Linux Mint/Ubuntu

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, linux-mint

I would like to configure triple monitors to act as a single screen in Linux Mint, similar to what Nvidia Surround does on Windows.  I'm  new to GNU/Linux systems and still finding my way, but I've gathered this is a non-native feature.  I haven't yet mangaged to find any posts directly on  topic that aren't years old.

I have three identical 1440p LG monitors on an Nvidia 3090.  The NVidia surround works pretty seamlessly in Windows 10 on the same machine.  Mint had no issues detecting and rendering the three screens; all I had to do was plug them in.  I tried playing around with the Nvidia X Server settings in Mint but no luck so far.  When I tried manually putting 7860 x 1440 in X Server settings, it showed an ultrawide rectangle but it only let me drag two screens in it or else one disappears.

I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.  Thanks.